# How to determine the order of the result from my postgres query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    time as "time",
    case 
       when tag = 'KEB1.DB_BP.01.STATUS.SOC' THEN 'SOC'
       when tag = 'KEB1.DB_BP.01.STATUS.SOH' THEN 'SOH'
    end as "tag",
    value as "value"
FROM metrics
WHERE 
    ("time" BETWEEN '2021-07-02T10:39:47.266Z' AND '2021-07-09T10:39:47.266Z') AND
    (container = '1234') AND
    (tag = 'KEB1.DB_BP.01.STATUS.SOC' OR tag = 'KEB1.DB_BP.01.STATUS.SOH')
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
    ORDER BY time desc
    LIMIT 2
```

This is giving me the result:

[image]

Sometimes the order changes of the result changes from SOH -> SOC or from SOC -> SOH. I'm trying to modify my query so I always get SOH first and than SOC.. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is uncommon for a query to have a `GROUP BY` clause but no aggregation functions. Is it that you expect duplicates that you want to remove? For that we'd rather use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `time`s that are identical.  The `order by` is only using `time` as a key.  When the key values are identical, the resulting order for those keys is arbitrary and indeterminate.  In can change from one execution to the next.

To prevent this, add an additional column to the `order by` so each row is unique.  In this case that would seem to be `tag`:

```
order by "time", tag
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show the two most recent rows. In your example these have the same date/time but they can probably also differ. In order to find the two most recent rows you had to apply an `ORDER BY` clause.

You want to show the two rows in another order, however, so you must place an additional `ORDER BY` in your query. This is done by selecting from your query result (i.e. putting your query into a subquery):

```
select *
from ( <your query here> ) myquery
order by tag desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

order by 1 desc, 2

(order by first column descending and by the second column)